# I know that $I=\int_AJ(\vec{r},t)d\vec{A}$ now can I say that $I(\vec{r},t)$?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that $I=\int_AJ(\vec{r},t)d\vec{A}$ and if $J(\vec{r},t)=\sigma(\vec{r},T) \vec{E}(\vec{r},t)$ we have $I=\int_AJ(\vec{r},t)d\vec{A}=\int_A\sigma(\vec{r},T) \vec{E}(\vec{r},t)d\vec{A}$ now can I say that $I(\vec{r},t)$?

Comment: In a word: no. Why do you think that you might be able to?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty .Because $\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)$ .So What does the current depend on?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say $I(t)$ but not $I(\vec{r},t)$. This is because $I=\int_A{\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)}\cdot d\vec{A}$. Note the dot product and vector variable $\vec{J}$, which you missed in your question. The dot product consumes the vector signs of both $\vec{J}$ and $d\vec{A}$, leaving $I$ directionless thus a scale variable. The $\vec{r}$ and $d\vec{A}$ are comsumed by the integration (you integrate over every small $d\vec{A}$ which is at the position $\vec{r}$), leaving $I$ not depending on $\vec{r}$. However, $I$ depends on $A$ which you have pre-defined. This is why you get $I(t)$ in the end. You may call it $I(A,t)$ if you want.